# R - annotating point in the splom and custom diagonal plots

Tags: r

I have a little example splom in R:

```
myData <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),z=runif(10),bin= factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE),labels = c("yes", "no") ))

splom(myData[c("x","y","z")],  diag.panel = function(x, ...) {
  yrng <- current.panel.limits()$ylim
  d <- density(x)
  d$y <- with(d, yrng[1] + 0.95 * diff(yrng) * y / max(y) )
  panel.lines(d)
 })
 #diag.panel from: http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/295-vis/splomdiag.html
```

I'd like to do two things.

1. color (and fill) the points in each scatterplot: red for the bin="yes" and grey for the points of bin="no"
2. Plot the % of bin (yes/no) in and overlay that on the diagonal histograms to assess the correlation of the % of bin by dist of x,y,z

Has someone already implemented this and willing to share the code?

Comment: Your second request doesn't make sense. In each of the diagonals, all of the values are plotted (in one, all of the `x`, in another all of the `y` etc). Since each diag plot represents the same set of observations (just a different variable) they all will have the exact same `% bin`. And your first request is usually done with the `groups=` argument in Lattice.

Comment: how about, instead of trying to boost your self esteem you just answer the queston with a groups example and note that yes, the 2nd question does make sense because even though the bins are the same you can compare the % by each histogram which is helpful. look forward to your brilliantly crafted example code.

Comment: There's a `groups=` example in the `?splom` help page and "% by each histogram" still doesn't make sense. That percentage would be the same for all diagonals based on how i'm interpreting your question. Feel free to edit your question to clearly give the numerator and denominator such that it would vary depending on the variable (x,y, or z) you plot.